# automaticlly bulk download images from servers path from a list of image links

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, batch-file, firefox-addon

I am trying to download product images from a server's path. (No FTP access) I have all the URL's of each image in a csv file but to enter in each URL into the browser and then right click and save is a bit tedious when you have 1000's of them. For instance, given the following.

```
http://www.thesite.com/path_to_image/someimage.jpg
http://www.thesite.com/path_to_image/someotherimage.jpg
http://www.thesite.com/path_to_image/anotherimage.jpg
http://www.thesite.com/path_to_image/andanotherimage.jpg
etc ...
```

Is there a script, program, FF add-on, batch type script or other method to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I'm a fan of the [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/) Firefox plugin.  But if you're looking for a standalone app, you can also try [jDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/).

Comment: Thanks you for the suggestions. I installed DownThemAll but I do not see any options that would allow me to enter in multiple image URL's and have them automatically save them in one shot. Can you perhaps explain where this may be in the plugin?